# How do I sublass a control along with its attached properties?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, datagrid, command, subclassing

I am trying to subclass `System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid` in order to add special commands to which a view model can bind.  How do I do this and still have the `Columns` attached property? Do I have to declare it against my new type in order to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Columns is not an attached property.. you should use it the same way you always do, just replace DataGrid with your-control-name:

```
<my:MyDataGrid>
  <my:MyDataGrid.Columns>
     <!--  Columns goes here --->
  </my:MyDataGrid.Columns>
</my:MyDataGrid>
```